# Vue datetimepicker - The month view show only 1 row

Tags: css, datetime, vue.js, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap-datetimepicker for Vue (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker) by CDN. The date layout is fine, but the month view size is not working properly when click to select month.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<datetime-picker v-model="checked_in_time" class="size_datetime_picker"
                             :config="{
                                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
                                widgetPositioning: {horizontal: 'auto', vertical: 'top'},
                                showClear: true,
                                useCurrent: false
                             }"
                             name="checked_in_time"></datetime-picker>
```

I use CDN to import file.
Please give me a hint to resolve this problem

Comment: use proper bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

Since this is based on bootstrap make sure that you have good class order "container" > "row" > "col-md-12" (or similar). After you do this try the following.

Try to replace your object in ":config" with object from "data" called "options". Something like this:

```js
 data: {
    date: null,
    options: {
      widgetPositioning: {horizontal: 'auto', vertical: 'top'},
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss',
      useCurrent: false,
      showClear: true,
      showClose: true,
    }
  },
```

```html
 <date-picker name="date" v-model="date" :config="options"></date-picker>
```

Comment: I add these order "container" > "row" > "col-md-12" but nothing happened :(

Comment: Can you please upload somewhere so I can have a closer look, maybe jsfiddle?

Comment: Thank you, I add 'float:left' in `.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td span` and resolve it.